# How do I take value with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

standard input, select box and multiple select box can also get the desired value, it works.. but how can i get the value with jquery in this code snippet?

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#checkboxesmarka').change(function(){
    var id=jQuery('#checkboxesmarka').val();
      alert(id);
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="checkboxesmarka">
<?php
while($markacek=$markasor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
  <label for="<?php echo "marka".$markacek['marka_id'] ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo "marka".$markacek['marka_id'] ?>" name="marka_id[]" value="<?php echo $markacek['marka_id'] ?>" /><?php echo $markacek['marka_name'] ?> </label>
    <? } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code will work if once you fix the logic to use the correct `id` or `class` selector

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Your loop can fetch more than 1 row, that means more than 1 element with the same ID - that's not good.

Comment: There is no id with the same identity. marka1, marka2, marka3, marka4 .... marka55, marka56 increases in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('#checkboxesmarka').click(function(){
    var valSelected = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      valSelected[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(valSelected);
  });
});
```

In console all selected value